# Extracting desired area from group of shapefiles, area remains same as original file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, clip

I have an output of a classified image as a polygon shapefile (call it File A, the larger, irregular shape in the screenshot below). I used the `clip (Analysis)` tool to extract a rectangular area in the center (inner green polygon in the screenshot).

[image]

My output is shown below. When I checked the area (square meters) of the purple layer I found that the area of output is almost equal to the area of file A. I would expect it to be much smaller. Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: If you mean something other than performing three different Clip operations, you'll need to edit the question to specify it. Otherwise your need to specify what went wrong.

Comment: Whenever I am trying the clip operation the output shapefiles get merged in one polygon. I want to get all the objects (classes) as in original one. Say, if I have 8 classes in the master (origin) file the output must have the same classes.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.  It should be noted that your comment doesn't make any sense. Please use a screenshot to explain your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Clip tool should do exactly what you want. It doesn't merge any features, it just clips your input file to the limits of your clip file. You could make sure the tool you're using is `Clip (Analysis)`, there are a few different Clip tools but the others are for rasters and coverages and should give an error message if you even try to use them in your situation.

If your input file has 8 classes, and features from 6 of those classes are included in the clip polygon (your red line), your output file will also have 6 classes. If it doesn't, something else is going on. I can't say what without more details, but you're using the correct tool for what your desired output is.

The graphic in the Clip tool help really says it all. If you're getting something else, you may be using the wrong tool:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sir for you reply but I am using Clip (Analysis) tool only. I don't know what wrong is happening.

Comment: @user2590251 Are you recalculating the areas in your output file (the smaller rectangle) after the Clip operation? If File A is a shapefile and it contains an Area field, that field in your output isn't updated automatically to reflect the new areas. You need to do it yourself using the Calculate Geometry command.